# UIPageViewController - Does not conform to protocol

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift3, uipageviewcontroller

I am trying to implement a UIPageViewController and I am getting the following errors: My code is the following

```
import UIKit

class ShopViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Which gives me an error that says: ShopViewController does not conform to protocol UIPageViewControllerDataSource.

So I found another thread suggesting that I add the following functions:

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController,      viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
```

After doing so my code is now:

```
class ShopViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

   func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?

   func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?

   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
   }
  }
```

But I still get an error saying the same + expected { in body of function declaration where I added the 2 new functions.

Can anybody help?

Comment: All you have done is define some functions which appear in the protocol.  You actually need to add *implementations* of those functions that do what you want. Ie. Add code to that returns the next/previous view controllers as appropriate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use it like this, as you are using `UIPageViewController` and you are not implementing the delegate methods `viewControllerAfter` and `viewControllerBefore` of `UIPageViewController` thats why you are getting this errors.

```
class ShopViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        // Returns the view controller after the given view controller.
        return self
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        // Returns the view controller before the given view controller.

        return self
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```